# How are you supposed to use the SSAS Tabular Measures Grid

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssas, tabular

As far as I can tell it doesn't do anything, and the best thing to do is to add all measures as a list in one column, but then there would be a "Measures List" instead of grid.... so what's the "grid" part do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason I can imagine is that you can put a measure below a column to which it refers somehow. This is obviously the case for the standard case of a measure being the sum of a specific column. But other than that, I agree there is no real use.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to double-check that it is purely for organization... it just seems that the entire UI suffers quite a bit from it being "superfluously" tabular